# URL Rewrite detection for HTTPS without using input="{HTTPS}"

Tags: .net, iis-7, url-rewrite-module

I need to redirect based on HTTP or HTTPS however our .net application is behind a load balancer that does SSL Offloading and therefore .net is not able to detect if the request is HTTP or HTTPS.

I want to implement a rule like the one below but instead of using input="{HTTPS}" I need to be able to detect whether HTTP or HTTPS is present in the actual URL.

In our case the code below always triggers because the website effectively non-https for all sites behind the SSL offloading.

```
    <rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect HTTP to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)"/>
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$"/>
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther"/>
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

We do have an x-ssl custom host header when SSL so I'm thinking something like this might work:

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
    <rule name="Redirect HTTP to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)"/>
        <conditions>
<add input="{HTTP_x_ssl}" pattern="1" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther"/>
    </rule>
</rules>
```

But the pattern="1" doesn't seem right.

Is there a way to say "If the host header HTTP_x_ssl exists then redirect to https:// else redirect to http://"

Comment: Use FRT to reveal what are the things inside incoming requests that you can utilize to write your rules, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: Thanks.  How can I  add a condition for if a header exists or not?